# How can I think of infimum of set sequence when there is no common intersection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to understand the limit, sup, and inf definitions of a sequence of sets.

Based on the answer to this: [What does the supremum of a sequence of sets represent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222192/what-does-the-supremum-of-a-sequence-of-sets-represent)

I think I can make an intuitive connection of $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n}$ being the union. However, the intersection of $A_n$ as $\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n}$ is a bit confusing to me. Based on my understanding, for an increasing sequence of sets, $ A_1 \subset A_2 \subset A_3 \subset \dots$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n = A$,  I can assume $\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n} = A_1$. Is this correct?

But how can I define infimum for a decreasing sequence of sets without the condition $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n = A$, for example, the set $A_n$ continuously decreasing towards the null set as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Is this possible? I am tempting to say $\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n}$ would be $\varnothing$ in that case...or do we just say the limit does not exist?

Lastly, if the sequence of sets do not have a common intersection for $A_n$ for all n, would $\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n}$ be simply $\varnothing$ as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $A_1 = [-1, 1]$, $A_2 = [-0.5, 0.5]$, so in general $A_n = [-1/n, 1/n]$. $0$ is in all of the sets so the intersection is not empty. So yes, if there is no intersection then the infimum would be the empty set.

Comment: Thank you! For your example, it means $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n = \{0\}$, right? So does it just not make sense to consider a decreasing sequence of sets without any intersection? Also, for the first part of the question, if we consider an increasing sequence of sets, infimum is simply the first set, right?

Comment: Yes it means $\bigcap A_n = \{0\}$. It makes sense to consider a decreasing sequence of sets without any intersection, it's just that it's empty. And yes, if the sequence is increasing then the infimum is the first set.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification!