# Brownian motion $\{B_t:t\ge0\}$: could it be shown that $\mathbb{P}(\{B_n/\sqrt{n}> c\text{ i.o.}\})\ge \mathbb{P}(\{B_1>c\})$?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, proof-writing, brownian-motion, limsup-and-liminf

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$. Let $\{B_t:t\ge0\}$ be a standard Brownian Motion. We know that: $$\{\limsup B_n/\sqrt{n}\ge c\}\supseteq \{B_n/\sqrt{n}> c\text{ i.o.}\}$$

---

Could it be shown that:
$$\mathbb{P}(\{B_n/\sqrt{n}> c\text{ i.o.}\})\ge \mathbb{P}(\{B_1>c\})$$?
If so, how? Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of events. Since for each $n\ge 1$, $\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}A_m\right)\ge \sup_{m\ge n}\mathsf{P}(A_m)$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n)&=\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{m\ge n} A_m\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}A_m\right) \\
&\ge \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup_{m\ge n}\mathsf{P}(A_m)\right)=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(A_n),
\end{align}
where the second equality follows from the [continuity from above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234292/continuity-from-below-and-above).
Applying this result to your case, one gets
$$
\mathsf{P}(B_n/\sqrt{n}>c\text{ i.o.})\ge \limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(B_n/\sqrt{n}>c)=\mathsf{P}(B_1>c)
$$
because $B_n/\sqrt{n}\overset{d}{=}B_1$.

Comment: So, second equality corresponds to:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{m\ge n} A_m\right)=\mathsf{P}\!\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup_{m\ge n}A_m\right)\right)\\&\overbrace{=}^{\text{by continuity from above}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\left(\sup_{m\ge n}A_m\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}A_m\right)\end{align}$$
right? One last fact: I know that $$\mathsf{P}(\bigcup_{m\ge n}A_m)\le\sum_{m\ge n}\mathsf{P}\left(A_m\right)$$by subadditivity. Why $$\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}A_m\right)\ge \sup_{m\ge n}\mathsf{P}(A_m)$$? @d.k.o.

Comment: While last fact is given by the fact that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(B_n/\sqrt{n}>c)= \limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(B_1>c)=\mathsf{P}(B_1>c)$. Last equality follows from fact that the event $(B_1>c)$ does not depend on the index $n$ and the first equality follows from $B_n/\sqrt{n}\overset{d}{=}B_1$. Correct? @d.k.o.

Comment: @Strictly_increasing What is $\sup_{m\ge n}A_m$?  The second equality is exactly as it appears in the answer.

Comment: Regarding the first inequality, $\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}A_m\right)\ge \mathsf{P}(A_m)$ for each $m\ge n$.

Comment: $\sup_{m\ge n}A_m$ is the supremum of the sequence $\{A_m; m\ge n\}$. I know that, by def.: $$\inf_{m\ge n}A_m=\bigcap_{m\ge n} A_m\text{ and }\sup_{m\ge n}A_n=\bigcup_{m\ge n} A_n$$ Is that correct? @d.k.o.

Comment: @Strictly_increasing I've never seen this notation. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222192/what-does-the-supremum-of-a-sequence-of-sets-represent

Comment: $\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}A_m\right)\ge \mathsf{P}(A_m)\text{ each }m\ge n$: so, $\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}A_m\right)$ is an upper bound for $\mathsf{P}(A_m)$. By definition of $\sup$ as the smallest upper bound, it must hold that $\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}A_m\right)\ge \sup_{m\ge n}\mathsf{P}(A_m)$

Comment: Finally, for brownian motion $(B_n)_n$ we are allowed to say that $B_n/\sqrt{n}\overset{d}{=}B_1$ by scaling invariance property of Brownian motion